# safari form validation works only in second button click, but works fine in IE 1st click itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I am using below jquery for form validation, the below code works fine in IE9 but in safari sometime its working in second time button click only.

For example,

i am entring correct email and wrong password, it shows error message, then i corrected password and clicked button, the error was removed but form did not submit, then i clicked again the button, it is getting submitted. This is occuring only in safari. i am using safari 5.1

As well as i think single ready function is enough, but i am using 2 ready function, which one should i remove without affecting existing functionality.

```
jQuery().ready(function domReady($) {
        $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
        $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
        $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
        $('#txtLogin_Id').watermark("Email Address");
        $('#txtPassword').watermark("Password");

        if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() != '') {
            $('#spnLoginErr').show();
            $('#spnLoginErr').html($('#lblLoginErr').val());
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");      
        }
        else {
            $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
        }

        $('#txtLogin_Id').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Please enter email address.");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );

        $('#txtPassword').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Password has to be more than 6 characters");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );

        $('#BtnLogin').click(function () {
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '' && $('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Please enter email address and password.");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
            }
            if ($('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Please enter email address.");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
            }
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Password has to be more than 6 characters");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
            }
        });


        (function errorMsgBasedhighlight() {
            if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() == 'Please enter a valid email address and  password.') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
            }
            else if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() == 'Please enter a valid email address.') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
            }
            else if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() == 'Please enter a valid Password.') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
            }
            else {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        })($);

        $('#txtLogin_Id').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed'); 
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#lblLoginErr').hide();           
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );
        $('#txtLogin_Id').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed'); 
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#lblLoginErr').hide();           
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );
    });
```

Comment: I heard that, if i remove jquery domready, i will work good, is that the case? i tried removing this but got some other problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out issue myself, it is because of 2 blur functions for same text box and rewriting the domReady

Below is the code

```
        $(document).ready{function(){ 
        $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
        $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
        $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
        $('#txtLogin_Id').watermark("Email Address");
        $('#txtPassword').watermark("Password");

        if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() != '') {
            $('#spnLoginErr').show();
            $('#spnLoginErr').html($('#lblLoginErr').val());
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");      
        }
        else {
            $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
            $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
        }

        $('#txtLogin_Id').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Please enter email address.");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );

        $('#txtPassword').blur(function () {
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Password has to be more than 6 characters");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#spnLoginErr').hide();
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        }
            );

        $('#BtnLogin').click(function () {
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '' && $('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Please enter email address and password.");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
            }
            if ($('#txtLogin_Id').val() == '') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Please enter email address.");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
            }
            if ($('#txtPassword').val() == '') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#spnLoginErr').show();
                $('#spnLoginErr').html("Password has to be more than 6 characters");
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:White;!important;");
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
                return false;
            }
            else {
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
                $('#MsgSucc').attr("style", "background-color:#dfe5e6;");
            }
        });


        (function errorMsgBasedhighlight() {
            if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() == 'Please enter a valid email address and  password.') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
            }
            else if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() == 'Please enter a valid email address.') {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').addClass('outLineRed');
            }
            else if ($('#lblLoginErr').val() == 'Please enter a valid Password.') {
                $('#txtPassword').addClass('outLineRed');
            }
            else {
                $('#txtLogin_Id').removeClass('outLineRed');
                $('#txtPassword').removeClass('outLineRed');
            }
        })($);


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
```

instead of

```
jQuery().ready(function domReady($) {
```

and write all events outside of document ready.

Comment: i tried this, may be i am missing something, can you post some example